# ¿Top de los palabra que mas repiten en txt en java?

Tags: java

Se puede hacer un top de un txt en java, de las palabras que mas se repiden , he buscado en muchos foros por respuestas pero no hay sobre ese tema.....................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................

```
public  void buscarCoincidenciaAviones(String letraBuscar, File archivo) {
    int totalCoincidencias = 0;

    try {
        if (archivo.exists()) {

            BufferedReader archivoLeer = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(archivo));
            String lineaLeida;

            while ((lineaLeida = archivoLeer.readLine()) != null) {

                String[] partes = lineaLeida.split(",");

                for (int i = 0; i < partes.length; i++) {
                    if (partes[i].equals(letraBuscar)) {
                        totalCoincidencias = totalCoincidencias + 1;
                    }
                }
            }

            archivoLeer.close();
        }

        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "\n\nEl caracter: " + letraBuscar
                + " se encuentra: " + totalCoincidencias
                + " veces en el archivo buscando por PALABRA");

    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

Comment: Ya tienes claro como leer archivos?
Podrias subir el contenido de tu txt?

Comment: vu1,QA,2000,01/07/2020,11:11,Internacional de Galeão,02/07/2020,20:00,Internacional de El Salvador,455,208130717,208920345,408910651,208930445,109820345,07:49
123,QA,344,01/07/2020,12:55,Juan santa maria,02/07/2020,20:00,Internacional de la Ciudad de México,455,208920345,208920345,208930445,109820345,109820345,06:05
455e,QA,566,04/07/2020,13:00,Internacional de Miami,04/07/2020,22:33,Juan santa maria,455,208130717,208920345,109820345,408910651,208930445,08:33

Comment: Este es mi txt deseo hacer un top de las palabras que mas se repiten

Comment: ahi esta mi codigo

Answer (score 0):

Puedes recurrir a un [HashMap](https://guru99.es/working-with-hashmaps/) para llevar la cuenta de cuantas veces se repite una palabra, personalmente me gusta mas usar Scanner para leer texto plano que la clase BufferReader pero esto es personal tu puedes seguir usando esa clase

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
    
    //le pasamos la ruta de nuestro archivo a la clase Scanner
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(new File("/home/jgarnica/Desktop/myinput.txt")); 
    
    //Creamos un objeto de tipo HashMap, buscar en google como funciona
    Map<String, Integer> ocurrences = new HashMap<String,Integer>();
    
    
    //Checo si hay mas lineas para leer
    while(sc.hasNextLine()) {
        
        //Se obtiene todas las palabras de una linea
        String[] words = sc.nextLine().split(",");
        
        //Recorremos palabra por palabra
        for(String word: words) {
            
            //si la palabra ya ha sido guardada en el HashMap entonces
            //sumamos uno al contatador 
            if(ocurrences.containsKey(word)) {
                ocurrences.put(word,ocurrences.get(word)+1);
            }
            //si la palabra aparece por primera vez entonces pone el contador a 1
            //para esa palabra
            else {
                ocurrences.put(word,1);
            }
        }
    }
    
    //Recorremos el HashMap para motras la palabra y la cantidad de veces que se repite
    for (Map.Entry<String, Integer> entry : ocurrences.entrySet()) {
        System.out.println(entry.getKey() + " - " + entry.getValue());
    }
}
```

PD: Solo faltaria orderna los elementos eso te lo dejo de tarea.

Answer (score 0):

```
/*
 1.- Diseña un programa capaz de contar cuántas veces aparece cada palabra en un texto. El texto se leerá
 desde un fichero cuyo nombre nos proporcionará el usuario desde la línea de comandos del sistema. Las
 palabras van separadas por carácteres en blanco, comas, puntos, punto y coma, salto de línea y tabuladores.
 El informe se dará ordenado de mayor a menor frecuencia de aparición.
 */


import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.StringTokenizer;

/**
 * @author javie
 *
 */
public class CuentaPalabra {

    public static HashMap<String, Integer> cuentaPalabras(String texto) throws FileNotFoundException {
      //  texto = "/home/jgarnica/Desktop/myinput.txt"; esto seria en linux
          texto = "C:\\Users\\javie\\Desktop\\defensa.txt"; //Asi en windows
        String saltador = " .,;\n\r\t";
        HashMap<String, Integer> letras = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
        java.util.Scanner teclado = new java.util.Scanner(new File(texto));
        String p;

        for (; teclado.hasNextLine();) {

            StringTokenizer linea = new StringTokenizer(teclado.nextLine(), saltador);

            for (; linea.hasMoreTokens();) {

                p = linea.nextToken();

                if (!letras.containsKey(p)) {
                    letras.put(p, 1);

                } else {
                    letras.put(p, letras.get(p) + 1);
                }
            }
        }
        return letras;
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) throws FileNotFoundException {
        System.out.println(CuentaPalabra.cuentaPalabras(""));
    }
}
```

Seria asi tuve que hacer un trabajo el cual  1.- Diseña un programa capaz de contar cuántas veces aparece cada palabra en un texto. El texto se leerá
desde un fichero cuyo nombre nos proporcionará el usuario desde la línea de comandos del sistema. Las
palabras van separadas por carácteres en blanco, comas, puntos, punto y coma, salto de línea y tabuladores.
El informe se dará ordenado de mayor a menor frecuencia de aparición.